# Way to Improve XML Writing in VB.Net

Tags: xml, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, xml-serialization

Good Afternoon,

I was wondering if anyone had any ideas to shorten my process for writing a XML. At the moment I'm at a Alpha stage with this so its really a mock up. But I've realised i'm only 1/4 of the way though and there's so many lines of code!

I've wondered could i use the xsd file in VS2012 - but I get a tad confused. Plus I would need it to talk to a database which it will be linked to later on, and also have xml fields that repeat if necessary.

Another thing, anyone got an idea to state almost ...

```vb
if Field is null then 

not write xmlfield
```

Something like that!

Many thanks in advance, i'm open to suggestions - but I also don't expect you to code it all for me - just a gentle nudge and advise if there's a easier way of writing such a large amount of data.

```vb
Sub XML()

    Dim theDate As Date
    theDate = Now.Date
    Dim ymd As String = theDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd")

    Dim enc As System.Text.Encoding

    enc = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")

    Dim settings As XmlWriterSettings = New XmlWriterSettings

    settings.Indent = True
    settings.Encoding = enc

    Using writer As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create("C:\Test.xml", settings)
        writer.WriteStartDocument()
        writer.WriteDocType("ONIXMessage", Nothing, "http://www.editeur.org/onix/2.1/reference/onix-international.dtd", Nothing)

        writer.WriteStartElement("ONIXMessage")
        writer.WriteAttributeString("release", "2.1")

        writer.WriteStartElement("Header")

        ' write next element 
        writer.WriteStartElement("FromCompany")
        writer.WriteString(My.Settings.PublisherName)
        writer.WriteEndElement()

        '' write one more element 
        writer.WriteStartElement("FromPerson")
        writer.WriteString(My.Settings.ContactName)
        writer.WriteEndElement()

        writer.WriteStartElement("FromEmail")
        writer.WriteString(My.Settings.PublisherEmail)
        writer.WriteEndElement()

        writer.WriteStartElement("ToCompany")
        writer.WriteString("sono")
        writer.WriteEndElement()

        writer.WriteStartElement("SendDate")
        writer.WriteString(ymd)
        writer.WriteEndElement()

        writer.WriteEndElement()

        writer.WriteStartElement("Product")

        writer.WriteStartElement("RecordReference")
        writer.WriteString(Form1.ebinfoISBN.Text & "_" & My.Settings.PublisherName)
        writer.WriteEndElement()

        writer.WriteStartElement("NotificationType")
        writer.WriteString(Form1.ebinfoNotificationType.SelectedValue)
        writer.WriteEndElement()

        writer.WriteStartElement("ProductIdentifier")
        writer.WriteStartElement("ProductIDType")
        writer.WriteString("15")
        writer.WriteEndElement()
        writer.WriteStartElement("IDValue")
        writer.WriteString(Form1.ebinfoISBN.Text)
        writer.WriteEndElement()
        writer.WriteEndElement()

        writer.WriteStartElement("ProductForm")
        writer.WriteString("DG")
        writer.WriteEndElement()
        writer.WriteStartElement("EpubType")
        writer.WriteString(Form1.ebinfoEBFormat.SelectedValue)
        writer.WriteEndElement()

        writer.WriteStartElement("Title")

        writer.WriteStartElement("TitleType")
        writer.WriteString("01")
        writer.WriteEndElement()

        writer.WriteStartElement("TitleText")
        writer.WriteString(Form1.ebinfoTitle.Text)
        writer.WriteEndElement()

        writer.WriteStartElement("TitlePrefix")
        writer.WriteString(Form1.ebinfoTprefix.Text)
        writer.WriteEndElement()

        writer.WriteStartElement("Subtitle")
        writer.WriteString(Form1.ebinfoSTitle.Text)
        writer.WriteEndElement()

        writer.WriteEndDocument()

        writer.Close()

    End Using

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes - don't use `XmlWriter`. Use LINQ to XML to build up the whole document in memory. It'll be *much* simpler. You can even use XML literals in VB if you really want to.

Comment: Thanks Jon. Looks like a much better idea! I've included it as a reference now. Do you know how to push it out to a file by any chance?

Comment: Yes, you use `XDocument.Save`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I write objects for easy XML Serialization in VB.NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/223526/how-do-i-write-objects-for-easy-xml-serialization-in-vb-net)

Comment: Don't think so, I'm looking to just export a file, not Serialise the data for settings :)

Comment: @PhillipBetts XML Serialization isn't just for settings.  You can serialize any data you want for any reason you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way of doing this by using LINQ

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Imports System.Linq

Dim documenttype = New XDocumentType("ONIXMessage", Nothing, "http://www.editeur.org/onix/2.1/reference/onix-international.dtd", Nothing)


    Dim Doc As New XDocument(documenttype)

    Doc = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>


          <ONIXMessage release="2.1">
              <Header>
                  <FromCompany><%= My.Settings.Var %></FromCompany>
                  <FromPerson><%= My.Settings.VAR%></FromPerson>
                  <FromEmail><%= My.Settings.var%></FromEmail>
                  <ToCompany></ToCompany>
                  <SendDate><%= ymd %></SendDate>
              </Header>


   Doc.AddFirst(documenttype)
    Doc.Save("C:\Tester.xml")
```

And I can continue to write it out line by line, as it would read when viewing the XML file.